# How to group joins in OpenSQL

Tags: sql, join, abap, opensql

I'd like to do the equivalent of

```
 SELECT * FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN (B INNER JOIN C)
```

using OpenSQL. Is this possible and what is the syntax?

Comment: Have you tried to define a view in SE11 and use that in the right-hand part of your query?

Comment: Nope, that might do it, good idea. Perhaps I'll revert to this solution if there is not other option. Introducing new views just for the sake of making queries work seems a bit overkill to me, though.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but the grouping needs to be an inline view in its own right. So, adapting your example here.

```
SELECT *
FROM A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT B.FirstColumn, C.SecondColumn, B.Thirdcolumn
        FROM B
            INNER JOIN C
        ) D ON A.Something = D.SomethingElse
```

No outer references - The inline view cannot reference columns from table A unless it is part of the inline-query in its own right.

Any more specifics would likely need more detail about your query and intent.

Comment: This does not seem to work. I tried this

    `SELECT *
      FROM but000 as a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT *
        FROM but000 as b
            INNER JOIN but000 as c on b~PARTNER EQ c~PARTNER
        ) as d ON a~PARTNER EQ d~PARTNER .`

but the compiler still complains about the parenthesis "not being in the dictionary" (note I added the 'as d' but without any difference).
Is there still something wrong with the syntax?

Comment: The column names in the inline view must be distinct to be addressable. I would use `.` and not `~`, and `=` rather than `EQ`, but that is mostly for dialect portability and ease of reading reasons.

Comment: made an edit, the column names for the inner view cannot be duplicated.